# Unable to remove missing ; before variable name error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compilation

```
#ifndef PRODUCTS_H
#define PRODUCTS_H
#include "Products.h"
class Products
{
protected:
    static int count;
    string name_;
    float cost_;
public:
    Products()  // default ctor
    {
        name_ = "";
        cost_ = 0.0f;
        count++;
    }
    Products(string name , float cost)  //parametorized ctor
    {
        name_ = name;
        cost_ = cost;
        count++;
    }
    Products(Products &p )
    {
        name_ = p -> name_;
        cost_ = p -> cost_;
    }

    ~Products()
    {}

    string getName()
    {
        return name_;
    }
     void setName(string name)
    {
        name_=name;
    }
    float getCost()
    {
    return cost_;
    }
    void setCost(float cost)
    {
        cost_=cost
    }
    float CalcTotal(Products *p_products)   //Not made yet!
    {
        float total=0.0f;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < count; i++)
        {
            total += p_products->cost_;
            p_products ++;
        }
        return total;

    }
    Products read()
    {
        Products size,*p_products;
        cout << "Enter Number of Items To Enter:";
        cin >> size;
        cout << endl;
        p_products = new Products[size];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < size; i++)
        {
            cout << "Enter Name:";
            cin >> p_products -> name_;
            cout << endl << "Enter Cost";
            cin >> p_products -> cost_;
            cout << endl;
            p_products ++;
        }
        return p_products;
    }
    void write(Products *p_products)
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++,p_products++)
        {
            cout<<"Products Name:\t\t"<<p_products->name_<<endl;
            cout<<"Products Price:\t\t"<<p_products->cost_<<endl;
        }
    }
};
#endif
```

**My source code is:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Products.h"
using namespace std;
static int Products::count;//declaring static variable
int main()
{
    Products *p_products,temp;
    *p_products=temp.read();
    //temp.write();
    system("pause");
    delete[] Product;
    return 0;
}
```

But I am getting this error which I can not remove:

> error C2146: syntax error : missing
>   ';' before identifier 'name_'

Please help me out!Thanks

Comment: Which line in your source file above does this error refer to?

Comment: It refers to the string variable declaration in my class

Comment: Is that the only error you get? It looks like there are plenty errors in this code. I'd suggest you to proceed writing little portions of code and continuously recompile it in order to keep it error-free...

Comment: @peoro:I am getting tons of errors.It was just one of the one's which were hard to debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should include the string header file in your first file. It looks like it's complaining that it doesn't know what a string is.

You need to add

```
#include <string>
```

and change the type of name_ to

```
std::string name_;
```

Comment: @fahad: Exactly what I told you in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/359902#359902)

Answer (score 2):

In `Products &p`, `p` is a reference to an object of type `Products`, it's not a pointer.

You have to use `operator .`, instead of `operator ->` in order to access reference fields:

```
Products(Products &p )
{
    name_ = p -> name_;
    cost_ = p -> cost_;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try moving this line:

```
using namespace std;
```

Above the line where you #include "Products.h". But if you're using string in products.h, you should probably be including  etc there instead. Also, I believe "using namespace std" is kinda frowned upon.

Comment: True, it's generally bad form to pollute the global namespace when all you really need is a string in a header file.

Answer (score 2):

in your include file, you must declare the string `name_` as `std::string name_`

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
std::string name_;
```

Also, looks like a missing semicolon here:

```
void setCost(float cost)
{
    cost_=cost
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a semicolon in this function:

```
void setCost(float cost)
{
    cost_=cost
}
```